# "Moments of best friends" or "Moments with best friends"

Tags: articles

> Best moments of best friends.

I wanted to name a picture with this which was taken with my friends. 
Or will it be more correct if I say Best moments with best friends.

And this sentence:

> Cassy and Cal resting outside with me, in an evening.

or will it be more correct to say

Cassy and Cal resting outside with me, in the evening.

But I'm not referring to today's evening. It was an evening long time ago.

Comment: You could also say "Best moments of our friendship." You are with your friends at that moment, but the moments are also part of your friendship with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Best moments with best friends.

and

> Cassy and Cal resting outside with me, in the evening.

Would be correct. But I would recommend:

> Cassy, Cal and me, resting outdoors in the evening.